# i have a pool heater to install the elect lists 208/240-575 vac 60hz 3 phase i have 175 ft from main panel what size sub panel and size wire to feed?

Tags: electrical-panel, subpanel, wire, heater, pool

I am going to install a separate sub panel for my pool. currently have a double 60 breaker supplying power to the pool pumps and am not sure if i can upgrade the current feed to accommodate the heater also, so probable just run it separately but not sure the feed size and main breaker size?

Comment: You don’t say what you are going to use to connect this 3 phase heater 208/240-575 v and how many watts is it? A double breaker in the US would say single phase 240. It may be possible to re configure to single phase though.

Comment: What size wire do you currently have running to the sub panel?

Comment: Do you have three phase power available at all?  And also posting the nameplate info of the motor would be helpful.

Comment: sorry this is the info i have from the specs. volts  230, hertz 60, phase 1, compressor amp 24.3, fan max load 2,4 A, fan HP 1/3, Min circut 40 amp max fuse 60 amp i was incorrect in the info i posted before. This sub panel will be pulled off the main panel in the garage and is approx. 175 ft to pump area were the heater will be installed. there is currently two pumps that are wired to the main panel with a 60 amp breaker

Comment: Can you post photos of the nameplate on said pool heater please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: You would have been much better off editing your [initial question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211556/what-size-wire-is-normally-run-to-a-pool-equip-area-during-new-construction) (even though it's now closed, it can be reopened with a good edit) to provide the details there instead of asking a whole new one. Please take the [tour] to get the feel for how this place works, since it's a little different than most discussion forums.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what size wire is normally run to a pool equip. area during new construction](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211556/what-size-wire-is-normally-run-to-a-pool-equip-area-during-new-construction)